# I want to change the compiler of a makefile from pgi to gfortran and I was wondering how I should change the FC and FFLAGS to make it work

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gfortran, compiler-flags, pgi

I have 5 makefiles which are designed for pgi compiler. However, my system is working with gfortran and I do not how to make them work with my system and how should I change FC and FFLAGS. I am new to Linux operating system and I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
Here are what the files contain:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
FC= pgf90
FFLAGS= -O -Mvect=sse -Mextend -Msecond_underscore -Mlfs -Bstatic

PROGRAM= mgn2mech
LIBS =   -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lioapi \
         -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lnetcdf
INCLUDE = -I/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/ioapi/fixed_src \
          -I/models/CMAQ/lib/netcdf-3.6.0-p1.mulcahy/include \
          -I$(CURDIR)/INCLDIR

OBJS = \
     checkmem.o \
     growseason.o \
     $(PROGRAM).o

MODULES= *mod.f

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# line to allow file.mod files to be recognised by GNU make
%.o : %.mod
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

.SUFFIXES : .f .f .o 

.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<
.F.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $(@) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) *.o *.mod *.core
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Next one:

```
FC = /usr/local/pgi/linux86/bin/pgf90
FCFLGS = -O -Mextend -Mbounds -Mlfs -Msecond_underscore
FCFLGS2 = -O -Mbyteswapio -Mextend -Mbounds -Mlfs -Msecond_underscore
LNKFLGS = -Bstatic

OBJCTS = \
met2mgn.o \
readpar.o \
readmcip.o \
micromet.o \
caldate.o \
lcpgeo.o \
interp_lcp.o \
procmm5.o \
readmm5.o \
xtod.o \
vertmap.o \
juldate.o \
utmgeo.o

LIBS = -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lioapi \
 -L/models/CMAQ/lib/netcdf-3.6.0-p1.mulcahy/lib -lnetcdf -lpthread
INC = -I/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/ioapi/fixed_src \
      -I/models/CMAQ/lib/netcdf-3.6.0-p1.mulcahy/include

met2mgn: $(OBJCTS)
    $(FC) -o met2mgn $(LNKFLGS) $(OBJCTS) $(LIBS)
met2mgn.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) $(INC) met2mgn.f
readpar.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS) $(INC) readpar.f
readmcip.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) $(INC) readmcip.f
micromet.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) $(INC) micromet.f
caldate.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) $(INC) caldate.f
lcpgeo.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} lcpgeo.f
interp_lcp.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} interp_lcp.f
procmm5.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} procmm5.f
readmm5.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} readmm5.f
xtod.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} xtod.f
vertmap.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} vertmap.f
juldate.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} juldate.f
utmgeo.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLGS2) ${INC} utmgeo.f
clean:
    rm -rf *.o met2mgn
```

Next one:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
FC = pgf90
FFLAGS = -O2 -Mdalign -Mnoframe -byteswapio -Mlfs -Bstatic
PROGRAM = ioapi2uam
LIBS = -L/models/MEGAN/MEGANv2.03a/lib/ioapi_3/Linux2_x86pg -lioapi \
       -L/models/MEGAN/MEGANv2.03a/lib/netCDF/lib -lnetcdf
INCLUDE = -I/models/MEGAN/MEGANv2.03a/lib/ioapi_3/fixed_src

RAW = $(PROGRAM).o

.f.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c -o $@ $<

.F.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c -o $@ $<

$(PROGRAM):     $(RAW)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $(@) $(RAW) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM)
```

Next one:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
FC= pgf90
FFLAGS= -O -Mvect=sse -Mextend -Msecond_underscore -Mlfs -Bstatic

PROGRAM= emproc
LIBS =   -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lioapi \
         -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lnetcdf
INCLUDE = -I/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/ioapi/fixed_src \
          -I/models/CMAQ/lib/netcdf-3.6.0-p1.mulcahy/include \
          -I$(CURDIR)/INCLDIR

OBJS = \
     gamma_etc.o \
     checkmem.o \
     canopy.o \
     solarangle.o \
     findlai.o \
     soilnox_fx.o \
     soilnox.o \
     $(PROGRAM).o

MODULES= *mod.f

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# line to allow file.mod files to be recognised by GNU make
%.o : %.mod
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

.SUFFIXES : .f .f .o 

.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<
.F.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $(@) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) *.o *.mod *.core
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Last one:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
FC= pgf90
FFLAGS= -O -Mvect=sse -Mextend -Msecond_underscore -Mlfs -Bstatic

PROGRAM= emproc
LIBS =   -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lioapi \
         -L/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/Linux2_x86pg -lnetcdf
INCLUDE = -I/models/CMAQ/lib/ioapi_3.mulcahy/ioapi/fixed_src \
          -I/models/CMAQ/lib/netcdf-3.6.0-p1.mulcahy/include \
          -I$(CURDIR)/INCLDIR

OBJS = \
     gamma_etc.o \
     checkmem.o \
     canopy.o \
     solarangle.o \
     findlai.o \
     soilnox_fx.o \
     soilnox.o \
     $(PROGRAM).o

MODULES= *mod.f

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# line to allow file.mod files to be recognised by GNU make
%.o : %.mod
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

.SUFFIXES : .f .f .o 

.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<
.F.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $<

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $(@) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) *.o *.mod *.core
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? And if so which errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the I/O API M3Tools *Makefile* template](https://github.com/cjcoats/ioapi-3.2/blob/master/m3tools/Makefile.template).

Note that the *ioapi/Makeinclude.${BIN}* files for the various types -- in this case, [`$BIN=Linux2_x86_64gfort` for *gfortran* before version 10, or `$BIN=Linux2_x86_64gfort10` for *gfortran* versions 10 or later](https://github.com/cjcoats/ioapi-3.2/blob/master/ioapi/Makeinclude.Linux2_x86_64gfort) will give you the flags you need.

Note also that this *m3tools/Makefile.template* is much better integrated with the underlying Models-3 I/O API than the one the code-author gives you....